# Determining the intersection of an arbitrary number of polynomials.

Tags: polynomials

Say $f_1,f_2,\dots,f_k\in k[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$, where $k$ is a field. Clearly, every $f_i$ is a polynomial.

How does one represent the intersection of all these polynomials? In other words, I want a polynomial which satisfies only the intersection points of **all** these polynomials, and no other point.

Comment: What do you mean when you say a polynomial "satisfies" a point?

Comment: And what is an intersection of polynomials?

Comment: My guess: he (or she) means that a point $x$ "satisfies" a polynomial $f$ if $f(x)=0$. Let $Z_i = \{x: f_i(x) = 0\}$. Then the intersection of the sets $Z_i$ is the set of points that "satisfy" all the polynomials $f_i$. He wants to describe this intersection set somehow.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified example, to avoid notational mess. Suppose we have two polynomials $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$. Then the sets $Z_f = \{ (x,y) : f(x,y)=0\}$ and $Z_g = \{ (x,y) : g(x,y)=0\}$ can be visualized as two curves in the plane. The intersection of these two curves will (in general) be a finite set of points. In fact, by [Bezout's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem), there will be $mn$ points, where $m = \deg(f)$ and $n= \deg(g)$, if you count appropriately and gloss over numerous details.

To construct a polynomial that is zero where $f$ and $g$ are both zero, you use a [resultant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of one sort or another (there are several).

This is a pretty fuzzy answer, with many details omitted, but it's no more fuzzy than the question, so perhaps it will suffice.